# Send associated Objects using SoapClient (PHP)

Tags: php, .net, wcf, soap

I want to send an object trough the SoapClient in PHP. How would I handle associations correctly? I don't know if this is the right format. On the WCF Side, I just get a `null` Person.

Lets say I want to send a Person with following Structure (Capitalized are the complex data types):

```
PERSON
--> PersonId
--> Name
--> Age
--> Gender
--> ADDRESS
   --> AddressId
   --> Street
   --> City
   --> Country
```

This is how I have tried so far...

```
$soapclient = GetSoapClient();

$person = array(
   'PersonId' => 123,
   'Name' => 'Tom'
   'Age' => 45
   'Gender' => 'Male',
   'Address' => array(
      'AddressId' => 424
      'Street' => 'Washington Street 2'
      'City' => 'Washington'
      'Country' => 'US'
   )
);

$soapClient->UpdatePerson($person);
```

Comment: What does `GetSoapClient` do? And would help to have a look at the WSDL XML. When I work with SOAP I use a lot the [`classmap`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)  option which basically lets you map the WSDL types to PHP classes.

Comment: It's a factory that creates the soap client. I will look at it, but I have already solved this problem. I will update the question asap.

Comment: Great then, [post your solution and select it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). And if you need some more help, post the WSDL.